# Net Core dependency injection in NuGet package

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, nuget

I have a NuGet package `Repository` which has an interface `IRepository.cs` and the implementation `Repository.cs`.

Is there a way to register the implementation against the interface (in the class library published as NuGet) so I don't have to do it in every project I am using the nuget ?

Comment: the max you can do is have an extension function that will account for future registrations  too

Comment: @NevilleNazerane I think you're right. I cannot think of another solution. Please post it as an answer. If any other solution comes up, I'll see then.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of Service Provider to use dependency injection internally in your class library.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton<IRepository, Repository>()
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        var repository = serviceProvider.GetService<IRepository>();
    }
}

interface IRepository {

    void Do();
}

class Repository : IRepository
{
    public void Do()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Do");
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no Program.cs in a nugget. Not in mines.

Comment: I meant if you need to use di in your class library internally, you can create instance of ServiceProvider and don't rely on for example ServiceProvider of asp.net core project. In this case you can initialize like code inside main method. you don't need Program.cs in your class library project.